# how to use MediaStore.download

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-download-manager

i'm creating an app to fetch and download file from Firebase Cloud Storage, the download part is using downloadManager, but i cant seems to open the file, and i want to put the downloaded file into a download folder inside android after downloadmanager do the job. its said to use MediaStore download for that, is that true? if thats true how you should approach it and apply mediastore download from myApp, if its not true, is there a better way to download the file and put the file accordingly for the user?

```
private void download() {
    //        ref = storageReference.child("User1/"+currentNrp+"_1.pdf");
    ref = storageReference.child("2023"+"/"+currentNrp+"_lab.pdf");

    ref.getDownloadUrl()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    String url = uri.toString();
                    downloadFiles(getActivity(), "2023"+"/",currentNrp+"_lab", DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, url);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "PDF Berhasil di download", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "PDF Gagal di Download, Silahkan Cek Kembali NRP anda atau " +
                                    "hubungi admin", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    //kondisi if ini membantu mengecek apa versi SDK/API cocok dengan codingan didalamnya atau tidak, dalam kasus ini apa setBackgroundResources itu cocok atau tidak
                    // atau mungkin artinya sedikit beda
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                        View toastView = toast.getView();
                        toastView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.toast_drawable);
                        toastView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                    }
                    toast.show();
                }
            });

}

private void downloadFiles(Context context, String folderName, String fileName, String destinationDirectory, String url) {

    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, destinationDirectory, folderName+fileName+ ".pdf");
    request.setTitle(folderName);
    request.setDescription(fileName);


    downloadManager.enqueue(request);

}
```

Comment: `want to put the downloaded file into a download folder inside android ` ? What do you mean?

Comment: `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context,....` Do you know where the downloaded file would be saved? Have a look at getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath().

Comment: Further i have no idea what you mean with MediaStore.download.

Comment: set download directory to public download directory You can use `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "nameOfFile");`